# Figma numeric stepper 1-999

Tags: figma, interaction

I have to create a numeric stepper component that goes from 1-999. I need to also add the function to choose the step size f.e 5 - when I click on “+” it will go like 5, 10, 15 etc

Any idea where to start?
Is there any plugin that could help me with this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you cannot take user input in Figma

And you can do this using component and States method.
And The second one is by several artboards.

**A)**

i) in method one create a button having plus and minus

ii) Make its component and then create its states like one, two, three and so on.

iii) Prototype on the same button component for a TAP action.

[image]

**B)**

Create several artboards having numerical counts on it, and then give a prototype for TAP action.

For your better understanding watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sU4itRTt0s0&ab_channel=UdayrajSathe)